# How to pass props in React Components correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have routes array, which pass into RouteComponent

```
const info = [
  { path: '/restaurants/:id', component: <Restaurant match={{ params: '' }} /> },
  { path: '/restaurants', component: <ListRestaurant match={{ path: '/restaurants' }} /> }
];
```

I use Axios for connection with back-end

**Restaurant Component:**

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.getOne();
  }
  getOne() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    Api.getOne('restaurants', match.params.id)
```

**Restaurant Component:**

When I see console there is en error like this
[image]

So, what can be passed as the props? Can't find solution. 
Thanks in advance

**App.js**

```
import ...
import info from './components/info/routes';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const routeLinks = info.map((e) => (
      <RouteComponent
        path={e.path}
        component={e.component}
        key={e.path}
      />
    ));
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          {routeLinks}
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

**RouteComponent.js**

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class RouteComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { path, component } = this.props;
    return (
      <Route path={path}>
        {component}
      </Route>
    );
  }
}

RouteComponent.propTypes = {
  path: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  component: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

**EDITED 22/03/2020**

Line with  gives this: *Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.*

Check the render method of `Context.Consumer`.

```
class RouteComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { path, component } = this.props;
    return (
      <Route path={path} component={component} />
    );
  }
}

RouteComponent.propTypes = {
  path: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  component: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
};
```

But as you see, I make PropTypes 'any'

Comment: Are you using `HashRouter` or `BrowserRouter`?

Comment: @norbitrial BrowserRowner

Comment: Show please how are you using `info` array and versions of `react` and `react-router`

Comment: @TalgatSaribayev edited post, check please

Comment: @RobertGurjiev so you want to go `http://localhost:8080/restaurants/123` and it will make GET request to `http://localhost:8080/api/restaurants/123`, right?

Comment: @TalgatSaribayev http://localhost:3000/restaurants/32 must be in front part. I have temporarily hardcoded 32 value. So, it should be 32 instead of undefined to controller part, but it is undefined -> 178 GET http://localhost:8080/api/restaurants/undefined 400

Comment: Please refer to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Ok there are some changes you will need to do and might not be enough. So let me know if does not work in comments.

**Step one**

send component correctly to routes

```
class RouteComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { path, component } = this.props;
    return (
      <Route path={path} component={component}/>
    );
  }
}
```

**Step two**

Send JSX element, not JSX object

```
const info = [
  { path: '/restaurants/:id', component: Restaurant },
  { path: '/restaurants', component: ListRestaurant }
];
```

Comment: in first case i have:  ×
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `Context.Consumer`.|


second one:TypeError: Class constructor Restaurant cannot be invoked without 'new'

Comment: You need both steps.

Comment: @TalgatSaribayed see my post, it is EDITED 22/03/2020. This occurs when these two steps are done

Answer (score 0):

Import RouteProps from react-router-dom and use it as the interface for props in routecomponent.js.

Then, instead of calling component via expression, call it like a component, i.e.

Eg,

```
function Routecomponent({ component: Component, ...rest }: RouteProps) {
    if (!Component) return null;

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
                <Component {...props} />
               />}
    )
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I may do something wrong.. I can't understand your code